# Using FeatureClassToFeatureClass from list to concatenated list?

Tags: arcpy

Have many feature classes in geodatabases and eventually want to run more complex processes on them. Having trouble with the basics - can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong with the following? If I use "print fcscopy" I get the list of output file names I want.. but the featureclass to featureclass gives following error.

```
#Code
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = r"D:\_StuData\GIS\Projects\PersonalProjects\Product\test.gdb"
fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses() 
copy = 'copy'
fcscopy = [x + copy for x in fcs]
outpath = "D:\\_StuData\\GIS\\Projects\\PersonalProjects\\Product\\test.gdb"

arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(fcs, outpath, fcscopy)
```

## Error

> Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "",
>   line 12, in    File "c:\program files
>   (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\conversion.py", line 1789, in
>   FeatureClassToFeatureClass
>       raise e RuntimeError: Object: Error in executing tool

## Testing

> `>>>` print fcs
>
> [u'Border', u'Building', u'Concrete', u'Grass', u'Gravel', u'Rocks', u'Roof']
>
> `>>>` print fcscopy
>
> [u'Bordercopy', u'Buildingcopy', u'Concretecopy', u'Grasscopy', u'Gravelcopy', u'Rockscopy', u'Roofcopy']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()` returns a list of the names of the feature classes.  However, `arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion` requires the path to the feature class.  You could incorporate something like this:

```
import os, arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = r"D:\_StuData\GIS\Projects\PersonalProjects\Product\test.gdb"

outpath = r"D:\_StuData\GIS\Projects\PersonalProjects\Product\test.gdb"

fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

copy = '_copy'

for fc in fcs:
    arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(os.path.join(arcpy.env.workspace, fc),outpath, fc+copy)
```

[**os.path.join**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) will "join one or more path components intelligently."

Comment: I think because the `arcpy.env.workspace` has been set the path to the fc isn't required (please correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: I haven't tested it.  But that's what I always use.  I've had issues in the past with this. Just looked at the documentation, however, and it appears you're right.

Comment: it won't hurt having the path there I'm sure

Answer (score 2):

FeatureClassToFeatureClass requires a single input/output, so you'll need to include within the for loop:

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = r"D:\_StuData\GIS\Projects\PersonalProjects\Product\test.gdb"

fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

copy = 'copy'
outpath = r"D:\_StuData\GIS\Projects\PersonalProjects\Product\test.gdb"

for x in fcs:
    arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(x, outpath, x + copy)
```